# mapbox-gl.js with PGRestAPI vector tile(pbf)

Tags: postgis, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js, vector-tiles

I have own vector tile from PGRestAPI, url like below
"http://192.168.1.4:3001/services/postgis/cleantech2/geom/vector-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"

and I try use mapbox-gl.js to render the map, but nothing display.

I am doing wrong? thx

```
var style = {
  "version": 8,
  "sources": {
    "countries": {
      "type": "vector",
      "tiles": ["http://192.168.1.4:3001/services/postgis/cleantech2/geom/vector-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
      "maxzoom": 6
    }
  },
  "glyphs": location.origin+location.pathname+"font/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "layers": [{
    "id": "background",
    "type": "background",
    "paint": {
      "background-color": "#ddeeff"
    }
  },{
    "id": "country-glow-outer",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "countries",
    "source-layer": "country",
    "layout": {
      "line-join":"round"
    }
  }]
};

var init_lat = 1.3552799//42.299228067198634;
var init_lng = 103.6945413;//-83.69717033229782;
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mapbox-token';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: style,
      center: [init_lng,init_lat],
      zoom: 15
  });
```

edit 1:

after debug mapbox-gl-js code, now can see several circles. I modify the style, the source-layer name from pbf must be correct.

but not display all the points, it seems filtered?

[image: sparse circles]

```
var style = {
        "version": 8,
        "sources": {
            "cleantech": {
                "type": "vector",
                // "url": "mapbox://map-id"
                // "url": "http://tileserver.com/layer.json",
                "tiles": ["http://192.168.1.4:3001/services/postgis/cleantech2/geom/vector-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
                "maxzoom": 6
            }
        },
        "glyphs": location.origin+location.pathname+"font/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
        "layers": [{
            "id": "cleantech2_geom_id",
            "type": "circle",
            'source': 'cleantech',
            'layout': {
                'visibility': 'visible'
            },
            'paint': {
                'circle-radius': 8,
                'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
            },
            'source-layer': 'cleantech2_geom'
        }]
    };
```

edit 2:
   change the maxzoom to 22, all data displayed. lets drink!

Comment: As far as I can tell, nobody has used PGRestAPI with GL JS. You may find this link helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125037/self-hosting-mapbox-vector-tiles.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: @LucasWojciechowski thx, see my edit. after give correct source-layer name, I can see some circles on the browser, but not all data rendered? do you know I miss some setting? btw, mapbox-gl-js is awesome, debug the code is very fun!  no errors in console.

Comment: all pbf data are points only,very dense

Comment: @max how you know source-layer from pgrestapi?

Comment: @Akram as I remember need print/debug the data at client side, then you find the name

Comment: Thanks Max. One more thing , you are still using PGRestAPI or moved to alternative?